# Vue.js 2 - For-Loop: Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vuejs2

I have a Component which loads the needed data via an API-Call. I save the response object into a data property

```
data() {
    return {
        productData: {},
        hasError: false,
        errorMessage: '',
    };
},
```

The save method looks like that:

```
if (response.data.status === 'error') {
  this.hasError = true;
  this.errorMessage = response.data.errorMessage;
} else {
  this.productData = JSON.parse(response.data.data);
}
```

Insight the data are some properties like name, ean and other and additionally an array of Objects. Now I write the Information of the productData to the template without any pain.
Than I try to iterate over the nested array of the product and I want to render a different component to encapsulate this behavior.

```
<supplier-item v-for="item in productData.supplierItems" :key="item.id"></supplier-item>
```

And that's the point where the pain comes in:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

The given link says nothing to me.
I can't understand the logic. How can an item - which is initialized insight the for loop - not be referenced during render.
Maybe someone can answer my question. I had this error as more as any other.
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you have an `item` somewhere else (outside of the `v-for` loop)?

Comment: No, it's only insight the for loop.

Comment: Try with other names and use the Vue devtools to be sure that everything is in order.

Comment: Read up on vue2 reactivity caveats, you have `productData.supplierItems`, but no `supplierItems` key in productData definition in `data` section.  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `v-if` if `supplierItems` exists like:

```html
<div v-if="productData && productData.supplierItems">
  <supplier-item v-for="item in productData.supplierItems" :key="item.id" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the issue OP is facing.